# About warning popup after gopls installation in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I installed gopls using command `set GO111MODULE=on` and `golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest` to use gopls.

After that, I restarted the program and whenever I write and save the source code, a warning window appears like the picture below.

[image]

I'm not sure what this warning means.

I am working on GOPATH and have all the packages I need.

But I don't know why i need a module here.

Comment: I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in "[GOPATH in the VS Code Go extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension)"

> Out of the box, the extension uses the value of the environment variable GOPATH. From Go 1.8 onwards, if no such environment variable is set, then the default GOPATH as deciphered from the command go env is used.

Check if you have set `go.gopath` or `go.inferGopath`.
Check what the returned value of `go env GOPATH` is.

More generally, it is a good idea to initialize a module at the root of your project (wherever your project is, GOPATH or not)

```
cd /path/to/my/project
go mod init myproject
```

---

Some issues mentioned that same error message

> You are neither in a module nor in your GOPATH.
> Please see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules for information on how to set up your Go project.

[Issue 36120](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36120) for instance said:

> I believe this is because my GOPATH is a colon-separated string:
>
> ```
> GOPATH="/Users/user/go:/Users/user/go-work"
> ```

But... that was fixed in [CL 211304](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/211304/) and [commit 74e303f](https://github.com/golang/tools/commit/74e303f875c6785dd66c8309307fa3803f714bd3) in gopls v0.3.2.

Comment: i test my $GOPATH in the terminal of vscode itself to be extra sure.

Comment: @Kelsnare Yes, what is its value? I have not used GOPATH in a while: a go.mod was all I needed since Go 1.11.

Comment: none at all when using go-modules. If not, maybe it'll be helpful when people have non-standard start up arguments in their default terminal emulator configuration that vs-code has no way of accessing

Comment: OK, but what is your Go version, and GOPATH value?

Comment: what does that have to do with this discussion? please understand that i'm not advocating the use of $GOPATH only. But if and when someone does need to use it for some reason with vscode-go - they might be better off testing it inside the terminal that vs-code provides. PS: I myself use go-modules pretty much everywhere without needing to interact with $GOPATH at all

Comment: @Kelsnare Your Go version then? Just to check what kind of feature is supported by your current environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208228/discussion-between-kelsnare-and-vonc).

Comment: @Kelsnare I have resumed the discussion in chat.